# Why does the UIScrollView automatically change contentOffset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, contentoffset

Question Describe :

My App have 2 tabbar item .
In the first Item , the viewcontroller have a view (the name is zpContainerView) ;
a scrollView, it's zpContainerView's subView ;
the scrollView add 3 subviews ;

Now , i touch the iphone's screen and change the scrollView's contentOffset ,

I click the second tabbar item , and soon after I click first tabbar item .

Question : Why does the scrollView automatically the contentOffset , why the contentOffset is CGPointZero ?

Please tell me why , and help me solve the question , thanks .

Comment: I think you'd better upload a image for your views' layout. Cannot understand question easily. :(

Comment: Please post code of `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

Comment: I find that If i click the second tabbar item , the scrollView did automatically call scrollView delegate and invoke [ scrollViewDidScroll: ] delegate method . I don't know why had happened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem 。

the ScrollView's class is not right .

Please look this : " UIScrollView * scrollView = [[UITableView alloc] init] ; "